# Are there any databases oriented toward write-only that are backed by append only bulk-readable file stores like Parquet?

Tags: database, parquet

For example, if you want to accrue observations and your read mode is reading "everything" or "a lot" all at once you really don't want a classic database, you want organized files.

To do this you end up writing a lot of uniqueness checking and ingress time code to append new observations. It feels dumb because databases are good at this. On the other hand running a database only to managed deduplication and indexing to then dump it all to parquet on update events seems dumb as well.

In financial HFT domains, you see memory mapped databases that always write to disk. Am looking for something like built on common formats like Parquet.

Does this exist? I have been looking for a while and have not found anything.